Can someone help me understand a typecast of a sockaddr reference when calling bind()?
I'm working on a small C++ program. The goal right now is to bind a TCP socket. I'm currently working on Arch Linux.
Here is the code I've currently written.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main() {

    sockaddr_in sockaddr {};
    sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr.sin_port = 8080;
    sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    int sockfd = socket(sockaddr.sin_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr, sizeof(INADDR_ANY));
}

The bind function is supposed to take the following parameters:

int s (socket file descriptor)
struct sockaddr *name (pointer to sockaddr struct)
int namelen (length of the socket addr in bytes)

It almost looks like a C style cast, but we are passing in a reference to the sockaddr_in struct. Is this taking the struct, and then casting it and de-referencing the variable?

You're confusing two uses of & character. When defining a type, it means a reference (so int& is reference to int), but when applied as operator it's address-of operator (so int a; int* p= &a; makes p point to a).

Any attempt to read man sockaddr? This is the C technique of polymorphism. You may consider sockaddr as a base class of sockaddr_in.

&sockaddr is the address of the object sockaddr; its type is pointer-to-sockaddr_in. The cast tells the compiler to pretend that the pointer's type is ponter-to-sockaddr (where this sockaddr is the name of the struct, not the original object).

Shouldn't sizeof(INADDR_ANY) be sizeof(sockaddr_in)?

You're probably adding to your confusion by using a variable with the same name as a structure type, sockaddr.

Side note working with raw sockets is a bit of a pain. For me the real question is WHAT would you like to do? Build a webserver? Build an interprocess communication channel? For both cases you will be better off using a library (e.g. boost/beast, or protobug/gRPC) both will help you do a lot of error handling for you.


It almost looks like a C style cast

It IS a C-style cast.

but we are passing in a reference to the sockaddr_in struct.

No, you are not passing in a reference, but rather a pointer instead.

Is this taking the struct, and then casting it and de-referencing the variable?

No.  You are passing in a pointer to the sockaddr_in object, and casting only that pointer.  The bind() function will use that pointer as-is to first read the sockddr::sa_family field (which overlaps the sockaddr_in::sin_family field in memory), see that it is set to AF_INET, and will then cast the pointer back to sockaddr_in* so it can access the sockaddr_in-specific fields.

It doesn't just look like a C-style cast, it is one. In C++ it would be preferable to write
reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&sockaddr)

The code was presumably copied from a C example.
As mentioned in the comments, &sockaddr is not a reference. & only makes a reference when it's used in the declaration of a variable or function. In an expression it's the "address-of" operator, which returns a pointer to the variable.
So we're taking a pointer to the sockaddr variable, which is of type sockaddr_in*, and converting it to the generic sockaddr* type that bind() requires.
If the sockets API had been written in C++ rather than C, it might have used function overloading or virtual functions for the bind() method. But it predated the development of C++ by many years, so it uses a generic pointer type and takes the actual length of the structure as a parameter, and requires that the pointer to the actual structure be cast to the generic type.
